# Como Puedo solucionar este problema en un Procedimiento almacenado en MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Saludos a la comunidad tengo este error en la creacion de este procedimiento almacenado en MYSQL

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
  DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE insertarnuevo15(
IN Vnumfact BIGINT(20),
IN Vserfact BIGINT(20)
)
BEGIN
  DECLARE Vnumfact BIGINT(20);
  SET Vnumfact = 0;

IF(SELECT serfact FROM factura WHERE serfact = Vserfact)> 0 THEN
     SELECT MAX(numfact)
     FROM factura
     WHERE serfact = Vserfact
     INTO vnumfact;
     SET Vnumfact = Vnumfact + 1;  
ELSE IF Vserfact = 0 THEN
    SELECT MAX(serfact)
    FROM factura
    INTO Vserfact;
    SET Vserfact = Vserfact + 1;
END IF;
END IF;
INSERT INTO factura (numfact,serfact) VALUES(Vnumfact, Vserfact);
  SELECT CONCAT('F',LPAD(Vserfact, 4, '0'), '-',LPAD(Vnumfact, 6, '0')) serial;

 END$$
```

Ahora ya corregido el error anterior me MUESTRA al momento de llamar el procedimiento almacenado.

```
CALL `prueba3`.`insertarnuevo`(1);
```

y cuando el select respectivo a la tabla factura me muestra lo siguiente y no inserta en numfact

```
codigo   numfact  serfact
  1         0       1
```

me genera el serial : F0001 000000

pero debería generar F0001 000001
muchas gracias

Comment: Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'in Vserfact);   SELECT CONCAT(F,LPAD(Vserfact, 4, '0'), '-', LPAD(Vnumfact, 6, '' at line 23 0.000 sec

Comment: eso que pusistes en un comentario, debe ir en la pregunta, ya que es tan importante como el codigo ;). agregalo usando el boton [edit]

Comment: Probaste ese select por separado?

Comment: Un par de detalles: 1) `... VALUES (Vnumfact,in Vserfact); ...`, debería ser `... VALUES (Vnumfact, Vserfact); ...`. 2) Falta cerrar uno de los condicionales `END IF;`.

Comment: wchiquito muchas gracias

Comment: bueno al llamar al procedimiento almacenado me genera un error espero su apoyo muchas gracias

Comment: Que es esa F en concat?

Comment: En la serie quiero que me genere F001  por eso coloque F,LPAD......

Comment: Me tiene que generar F001 000001

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dejo la solución

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `insertarnuevo1`(
IN Vnumfact BIGINT(20),
IN Vserfact BIGINT(20)
)
BEGIN


IF(SELECT serfact FROM factura WHERE serfact = Vserfact)> 0 THEN
     SELECT MAX(numfact)
     FROM factura
     WHERE serfact = Vserfact
     INTO Vnumfact;
     SET Vnumfact = Vnumfact + 1;  
ELSE
IF Vserfact = 0 THEN
    SELECT MAX(serfact)
    FROM factura
    INTO Vserfact;
    SET Vserfact = Vserfact + 1;
END IF;
end if;
INSERT INTO factura (numfact,serfact)
  VALUES(Vnumfact, Vserfact);
  SELECT CONCAT('F',LPAD(Vserfact, 4, '0'), '-',LPAD(Vnumfact, 6, '0')) serial;

 END$$
```